# Porque el Layout en esta calculadora no se ajustan al marco?

Tags: java, layout

Estuve programando una calculadora en Java y tengo un problema con la vista del mismo, ya que el layout (o la lamina) esta ocupando solo la mitad del mismo.

No entiendo que estoy haciendo mal, ya que el Layout no se esta ajustando correctamente al JFrame o al JPanel de la aplicaciones.

Estuve revisando el codigo, pero no puedo entender que puede ser, incluso estoy dudando si esta bien el programado el GridLayout(), y veo que si, que creen que puede ser este inconveniente?

Gracias y saludos de antemano!

Gonzalo

```html
   package com.nuevavida.calculadora;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Calcu{

public static void main(String[] args) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 
 MarcoCalculadora marco=new MarcoCalculadora();
 
 marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 
 marco.setVisible(true);

}

}

class MarcoCalculadora extends JFrame{
 
 MarcoCalculadora(){
  
  setBounds(600,200,450,300);
  
  setTitle("Calculadora");
  
  LaminaCalculadora laminaPantalla=new LaminaCalculadora();
  
  add(laminaPantalla,BorderLayout.NORTH);
 }
}

 class LaminaCalculadora extends JPanel{
  
  LaminaCalculadora(){
   
   sincero=true;

   setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   
   pantalla=new JButton("0");
   
   add(pantalla, BorderLayout.NORTH);
   
   pantalla.setEnabled(false);
   
   laminaBotones=new JPanel();
   
   add(laminaBotones,BorderLayout.CENTER);
   
   laminaBotones.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));
   
   InsertaNumero insertar=new InsertaNumero();
   
   AccionOrden orden=new AccionOrden();
   
   PonerBoton("7", insertar);
   
   PonerBoton("8", insertar);
   
   PonerBoton("9", insertar);

   PonerBoton("/", orden);

   PonerBoton("4", insertar);

   PonerBoton("5", insertar);

   PonerBoton("6", insertar);

   PonerBoton("*", orden);

   PonerBoton("1", insertar);
   
   PonerBoton("2", insertar);

   PonerBoton("3", insertar);

   PonerBoton("-", orden);

   PonerBoton("0", insertar);

   PonerBoton(".", insertar);

   PonerBoton("=", orden);
   
   PonerBoton("+", orden);
   
   ultimaOperacion="=";

  }
  
   
   public void PonerBoton(String botonInsertar, ActionListener oyente) {
    
    boton=new JButton(botonInsertar);
    
    laminaBotones.add(boton); 
    
    boton.addActionListener(oyente);
   
  }
  
  private class InsertaNumero implements ActionListener{
   
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
     
    if(sincero){
     
     pantalla.setText("");
    }
    
    sincero=false;
    
    entrada=e.getActionCommand(); // getActionCommand: CAPURA LA ACCION DEL COMANDO ASOCIADO, EN ESTE CASO EL NUMERO DEL BOTON PRESIONADO
    
    pantalla.setText(pantalla.getText() + entrada );
    
    }
    
   }
  
  
   
   


   
  
  private JPanel laminaBotones;
  
  private JButton boton,pantalla;
  
  private boolean sincero;
  
  private String entrada, ultimaOperacion;   
  
  private double resultado;
  

 }
```

Comment: En el constructor `MarcoCalculadora` cambia la posición del `BorderLayout.NORTH` a `BorderLayout.CENTER`

Comment: Mil gracias. Solucionado!